# How to add default namespace to generated class for C# in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I add an C# class to project, the class has some default namespaces like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
```

I want to add some default namespace when I add some new class to project. For example when I added new class to project I have following generated namespace by `Visual Studio`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MyCompany.Namespace1;
using MyCompany.Namespace2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [Visual Studio Item templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms247069%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You can create a new item template that contains whatever boilerplate code you'd like, then distribute that item template to your team members.

Comment: I want an applicable example please.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I know learned how to create some template. It is really useful.